# OpenGL loader Reason to #define function pointer

Tags: opengl

In the OpenGl-loader I've used (GLLoaderGenerator, GLEW) the header looks something like:

```
extern void (CODEGEN_FUNCPTR *_ptrc_glBindVertexBuffer)(GLuint, GLuint, GLintptr, GLsizei);
#define glBindVertexBuffer _ptrc_glBindVertexBuffer
```

... ok, GLEW hides this behind a couple of macros, but it results in pretty much the same.. 
So my question is - Is there a particular reason to define a function pointer with some name (_ptrc_XXX) and the #define the name I do want to use? Why not simply using:

```
extern void (CODEGEN_FUNCPTR *glBindVertexBuffer)(GLuint, GLuint, GLintptr, GLsizei);
```

Comment: Since the `#define` is just a rename, it would work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to avoid namespace collisions. The names specified by OpenGL and the OpenGL extensions are reserved for the use by OpenGL *implementations*. Later versions of the various operating systems OpenGL standard ABI^1 may suddenly expose symbols in that namespace, which would break programs being linked with libraries, that also define these symbols.

An extension loader library is not an OpenGL implementation, but a 3rd party library. As such it is good practice not tread into the namespace reserved to OpenGL, i.e. symbols beginning with `gl…`. Instead such extension loaders load the symbols into their own namespace, like `_ptrc_glew…` and use some preprocessor macro trickery to transparently "rename" symbol references in code that uses that library.

---

1: ABI = specifications on what a certain API has to provide and how the interface is done on the lower level.